# Redirect ajax request from controller model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I have this ajax function where I send a post request, the post request supposed to redirect from controller not from Ajax, How do I do that

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Project/AllDetails",
  data: { "SearchCriteria": JSON.stringify(AdvancedSearchModels) },
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    $("#AdvancedSearchFormModel").modal('hide');
    console.log('done');
  }
});
```

My controller:

```
public IActionResult AllDetails(string SearchCriteria)
{
  IEnumerable<Project> projects = _projectService.getAll();
  var list =new  List<AllDetailsModel>();

  if (SearchCriteria != null)
  {
    // do something
  }

  var model = projects       
  return View(model);
}
```

I know that ajax wait for response, but is there a way to actually redirect from controller while using jquery?

Comment: In `data` in your AJAX callback, you have returned object from your controller, i.e. `View(model)`

Comment: yes I know, but I want it this way, I need the object because it contain the list of data I need to set in the table

Comment: What table? In a view? Why not just pass this data to controller?

Comment: I do pass the data to the controller which then redirect to the view, However when I use ajax, I don't receive that data from controller ??

Comment: What data you want to recieve? You said that it's data for controller, not for front end